# Send HttpRequestMessage in C++, Windows API UWP

Tags: c++, uwp

This is not C++/CLI. This is UWP C++/CX

I am trying to send an HttpRequestMessage outside of a managed class in C++. I looked at the UWP samples, but their requests occur inside of a managed class.

All I want to do is send the request, and then have a callback function. I don't need fancy async/await patterns. This is looking to be a lot more difficult than it should be.

EDIT: I have gotten it to work, but the error handling is atrocious. The extra error handling code from the UWP HttpClient example was not compiling.

```
client = ref new Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient();
client->DefaultRequestHeaders->UserAgent->Append(ref new Windows::Web::Http::Headers::HttpProductInfoHeaderValue("Windows", "10"));
cancellation_token_source cancellationTokenSource = cancellation_token_source();

create_task(client->SendRequestAsync(message)).then([=](Windows::Web::Http::HttpResponseMessage^ response)
    {
        auto operation = response->Content->ReadAsBufferAsync();
        auto task = create_task(operation);
        if (task.wait() == task_status::completed)
        {
            webResponse->statusCode = (int)response->StatusCode;
            auto buffer = task.get();
            size_t length = buffer->Length;
            if (length > 0)
            {
                Array<byte>^ array = nullptr;
                CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray(buffer, &array);
                webResponse->contentLength = array->Length;
                webResponse->data = (byte*)malloc(webResponse->contentLength);
                memcpy(webResponse->data, array->Data, webResponse->contentLength);
                delete array;
            }

            for each(IKeyValuePair<String^, String^>^ pair in response->Headers)
            {
                std::string key = PlatformStringToString(pair->Key);
                std::string value = PlatformStringToString(pair->Value);

                if (key == "Content-Type" && false)
                {
                    // Should have this for completeness, but do we really care?
                }
                else
                {
                    Web::WebHeader *header = new Web::WebHeader(key.c_str(), value.c_str());
                    webResponse->AddHeader(header);
                }
            }

            if (request->receiveDoneCallback)
                request->receiveDoneCallback(webResponse, request->userPtr);
        }
        else
            abort();

        delete request;
        delete response;
    });
```

Comment: Could you please detail what  "outside of a managed class" you mean here? What sample you are reference?

Comment: I mean from a non-C++/CX function. like 'static void Blah()'. I am familiar with working with the old WinHTTP API.

Comment: I 'm still not sure what you actually want. Did you just want to send a Http request in a uwp app with standard C++ language instead of C++/CX? Could you please tell which sample you are reference?

Comment: I have gotten it to work, but the code is not clean at all, and there is no error handling. I don't remember which example, it was the HttpClient C++/CX UWP sample. What's the proper way to handle errors here?